# Jetty, preflight and ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jetty

Having a Jetty server set up programmatically which I try to access via ajax and xmlHttpRequest. Without authorization, the call works fine but with, I get 401 Unauthorized.
Any suggestions.

Javascript call looks like this (shortened):

```
var auth = base64encode('name','pwd');
try{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5563/ajax/index.html", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
    xmlhttp.withCredentials = 'true';
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
    $('#textResult').val(xmlDoc);
}
catch(e){
    $('#textResult').val('CATCH: ' + e);
}
```

Server code looks like this (even shorter)

```
class CallObject extends HttpServlet {
    //...
    @Override
    public void doOptions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException
    {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                       "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                       "X-Requested-With, authorization");
    }
//...
}

class WebServer{
//...
    SecurityHandler sh = null;
    if (logins != null && logins.length > 0){
        String role = "user";
        sh = new SecurityHandler();
        Constraint constraint = new Constraint();
        constraint.setName(Constraint.__BASIC_AUTH);
        constraint.setRoles(new String[]{role});
        constraint.setAuthenticate(true);
        ConstraintMapping cm = new ConstraintMapping();
        cm.setConstraint(constraint);
        cm.setPathSpec("/*");
        HashUserRealm hur = new HashUserRealm();
        hur.setName("eMark Web Server");
        for (int i = 0; i < logins.length; i++) {
            String user_name = logins[i][0];
            String password = logins[i][1];
            hur.put(user_name, password);
            hur.addUserToRole(user_name, role);
        }
        sh.setUserRealm(hur);
        sh.setConstraintMappings(new ConstraintMapping[]{cm});
        _server.setHandlers(
            new Handler[]{sh, _contexts, new DefaultHandler()});
    }
//...
}
```

Comment: I guess this will be of use to you [1].(http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+Configure+Security+with+Embedded+Jetty). I can also see that the credentials you are entering from javascript is "var auth =  base64encode('name','pwd');". That means the  credentials for 'name' is 'pwd' and it should be present at jetty with relevant role

Comment: Why do you set the "Authorization" request header on the client code directly? Why not use XmlHttpRequest support for authentication in the open() method?
Also, not sure whether your base64encode function formats the auth variable as "name:pwd".

Comment: It looks like you are making an async request, but trying to read the response synchronously?  Is that just a simplification that you made when posting this question?  If not, you will need to assign a callback function to the `onreadystatechange` property of the `xmlhttp` object.

Answer (score 1):

What does your `base64encode` function do with the two parameters? The `Authorization` header's value must be the base64 encoded value of the string `username:password`. (Note the colon.)

Note: for same origin XMLHttpRequests, you can provide the username and password as a parameter to the [open](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-open) method.

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization header should look like the following example:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

Where the text appearing after "Basic" is a base64 encoding of :

Check this link for more information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication